# How can i export the liquid physics in Three.js?

Tags: export, fluid-simulation, three.js

Please Let me know any format which helps in exporting physics

Comment: I don't think this is possible, aside from exporting each step of the animation to a separate geometry file (e.g. OBJ). ThreeJS is a realtime engine and does not do liquid physics.

Comment: Oh that means I cant export it for Three.js, but i can still export physics(e.g. in Fbx). correct??

Comment: I'm not sure whether FBX or the Blender FBX exporter support physics, sorry.

Comment: thanks for your reply @DonMcCurdy. have a good day